# UIAlertAction accessing old class variable

Tags: ios, swift, alerts, uialertaction

I have programmatically added `UITextView`'s and a class object that gets some part of it changed upon calling:

```
textViewShouldEndEditing(textView: UITextView)
```

I handle saving the object fields for the user as a batch save, but the problem is that the last edited `UITextView` value doesn't ever make it to the save, even though the `textViewShouldEndEditing` function gets called.  The only other complication is that the batch saving is part of a confirmation message via `UIAlertAction`.

To clarify, the class object that the `UIAlertAction` accesses appears to be out of date even though all functions are called in the correct order.  I hope this is clear.

```
var tmpGuest:VIG = VIG()

func textViewShouldEndEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    let saveTxt:String = (textView.text == "--" ? "" : textView.text)
    //SET SOME tmpGuest VALUES HERE
    return true
}

@IBAction func editInfo(sender: AnyObject) {
    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you wish to save?", message: "Changes are permanent.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        //SAVE 
        self.setGuest.setRecords(guestMainTmp: self.tmpGuest)
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(okAction)

    self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that reproduces this problem.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it that the UIAlertAction accesses an old class object? If so, I would advise breakpointing where you present the UIAlertAction and figure out why the class object is "out-of-date".

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.  I used BP and the functions are in the right order but when within okAction the class variable is out of date, even though at the previous BP (at return true) it is up to date.